# ORACLE - If in SELECT Statement

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a select and I need to hide data in a column when some other column meets criteria. Is there a way to do that in Select statement ?

Here is what I tried:

```
SELECT acc.account_no, (case substr(acc.bank,18,3) when acc.account_no like'%011006000%'  then ' ' end) "BANK_ACCOUNT", sum(acc.bills) "BILLS"
FROM BNK.Bank_Transaction acc 
WHERE acc.Bill_Date BETWEEN  '01.05.2018' AND '29.05.2018' 
AND (acc.account_no LIKE '%011006000%' 
OR acc.account_no LIKE '%011076000%')
```

I receive **ORA-00905: missing keyword** error in upper select.

Comment: count the parentheses in your where condition. also, if you need to check against a date, do not rely on implicit conversions, but use a date, for example `date '2018-05-01'`

Comment: @Aleksej, sorry that was a typo, I removed parenthese before where condition. But result is still with same error. Could I use DECODE function in my case ?

Comment: what should that case do? you do a substr of a column and then check the value of a different column againts a value, try to explain the logic you need to implement

Comment: @Aleksej, **substr** is what that column should be. But in case **when account_no is like '%011006000%'** then that **substr** column should be null. That is all point, I hope you understand now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need:

```
select case when account_no like '%011006000%'
         then null
         else substr(..)
       end as yourColumn,
       ...
from ...
```

Comment: and how can I use this in select statement ?